# Properties Editor : Scene : Color Management

Tags: color

This is probably a dupe, but nothing so far helps. The manual says "Properties Editor : Scene : Color Management." I have searched and searched here, the manual, and in Blender itself. I need to FIND Color Management. Please tell me exactly HOW.

Answer (score 1):

The color management is in the properties panel. If you don't know where the properties panel is, its over here:
[image: properties]

Now, go to the scene panel, its the third one:
[image: scene]

over here you will find colour management
[image: colourmanagement tab]

If its closed, open it up by pressing the arrow

[image: colour manage ment]
 if you still can't find it please post your .blend file over here
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/